# Injective hull of the trivial k[x]-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Here is the problem

> Let k be an algebraically closed field. Describe the injective hull of the trivial $k[x]$-module (The trivial module $k[x]/(x)$).

Someone suggested to me that the answer should be $k[x, x^{-1}]/k[x]$. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints:* Since $k[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, a module is injective if and only if it is divisible. Now, to show $k[x]$-divisibility of $k[x^{\pm 1}]/k[x]$, note that any element of $k[x]$ has the form $x^n\cdot P$ with $P(0)\neq 0$, so you may reduce to showing that $\cdot x^n$ and $\cdot (1 + xQ)$ are surjective on $k[x^{\pm 1}]/k[x]$. Can you do that?

Comment: I have a serious question. In order to show that these two maps are surjective, should I show that the cokernel of the maps are both equal to zero, or should I utilize a direct definition of surjective?

Comment: In this case you can show surjectivity directly. For $\cdot x^n$, note first that elements of $k[x^{\pm 1}]/k[x]$ can be uniquely represented as $a_k x^{-k}+a_{k-1}x^{-(k-1)}+…+a_1 x^{-1}$, and look at how $\cdot x^n$ acts on these representatives. For $\cdot(1+xQ)=1 + \cdot xQ$, the point is to note that $\cdot xQ$ is nilpotent - do you remember statements about the sum of the identity and a nilpotent map?