# Finding the injective hull

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let's suppose that I have an element $e$ of order $p$ in the group of complex numbers whose elements all have order $p^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (henceforth called $K$), and the module generated by $(e)$ is irreducible.

How do I show that the injective hull of the module generated by $(e)$ is in fact, equal to $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The abelian group of complex numbers that are $p^n$-th roots of unity for some $n$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}\left[\frac{1}{p^n}\right]/{\mathbb Z}$, with the submodule generated by the $p$-th roots of unity corresponding to ${\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{p}$. Now the strategy is exactly the same as for [Injective hull of the trivial k[x]-module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864801/injective-hull-of-the-trivial-kx-module) (can you see the common generalization of these examples?).